# Explain RosTextView

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the android_tutorial_pubsub package and have built an app that publishes to a node and subscribes to another. I also have two RosTextView widgets, which I want to display activity over my "publishing" rostopic and my "subscribing" rostopic. the tutorial has built-in functionality to display the publisher's messages on the RosTextView, but I cannot seem to get the subscriber messages to do the same. All the nodes and topics are set up correctly [per rxgraph], but I do not understand RosTextView enough to know how it gets its information or if subscriber should be pushing new messages to it.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42689/explain-rostextview/) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Srogacki,

I know this is a little late and you've already probably worked it out, but the RosTextView widget is a subscriber attached to a TextView. As per the basic ROS concepts a subscriber must be subscribed to a the message generated by a Publisher. As such any subscriber doesn't generate any messages but only listens to those made by a Publisher. I guess a better description of a RosTopic is a message channel between at least one publisher and one subscriber.

As this is the case, the subscriber in the RosTextView cannot subscribe to the messages from another subscriber, because your "subscribing" node does not generate any. The only way to see the messages your "subscribing" node might be listening to is to have your RosTextView subscribe to the same publisher over the same topic.

Hope this helps

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-02**:
Now I got it, but still a question: can I put the rosTextView subscriber listening to a server Publisher? if Yes, Why in the android_core/ android_tutorial_pubsub it didn't work ( keeping in mind that the only thing I've changed is the topic name of rosTextView of MainActivity.java of the pubsub tutorial inside android_core.